# Creating a dictionary from excel file with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

i'm new to coding and I would like to create two different dictionaries from an excel file that looks like this:

| Id | Object | kg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1142 | Apple | 17,5 |
| 1143 | Banana | 13,55 |
| 1144 | Kiwi | 52,3 |

I need that the first dictionary look like this {(1142:apple),(1143:banana),(1144:kiwi)}
and the second one to look like this {(1142:17,5),(1143:13,55),(1144:55,3)}

I need to do this using openpyxl and python3.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your current attempts and describe which *specific* parts you are having problems with. Do you know how to read an Excel file with openpyxl? Do you know how to read each row and get the value of each cell? Do you know how to form a loop to populate a dictionary? This is not a tutorial or "write the code for me" site.

Comment: By the way, `{(1142:apple),(1143:banana),(1144:kiwi)}` is not a valid dictionary. Do you mean this `{1142: 'apple', 1143: 'banana', 1144: 'kiwi'}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 using a for loop.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('openpyxl.xlsx')
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
for row in wb.worksheets[0].iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=4, max_col=3):
    dict1[int(row[0].value)] = row[1].value
    dict2[int(row[0].value)] = row[2].value

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

Method 2 using Dictionary Comprehension

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('openpyxl.xlsx')
dict1 = {(int(row[0].value), row[1].value) for row in wb.worksheets[0].iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=4, max_col=3)}
dict2 = {(int(row[0].value), row[2].value) for row in wb.worksheets[0].iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=4, max_col=3)}

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

results:

```
{1142: 'Apple', 1143: 'Banana', 1144: 'Kiwi'}
{1142: '17,5', 1143: '13,55', 1144: '52,3'}
```